# Dynamic DNS at freedns.afraid.org using a Fritz!Box

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6, dynamic-dns, fritzbox

I am having some trouble setting up Dynamic DNS with my Fritz!Box 7360.

I have set up the Dynamic DNS page with (this is translated from German, so might be worded a bit differently):

```
[x] Use dynamic DNS
Dynamic DNS Provider: User defined
Update-URL: https://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?MY-DIRECT-URL-KEY
Domain Name: mydomain.crabdance.com
User Name: myusername
Password: mypassword
```

Now on the FritzBox status page, it says:

```
Dynamic DNS: activated, mydomain.crabdance.com, Status: Account temprarily deactivated
```

When I check back on http://freedns.afraid.org, my IP address never changes. Is there any way to fix this?

Note my router is on an IPv6 network (m-net), with IPv4 only through DS-Lite. I'm not sure whether this affects anything.

**Update:** Following the guide [here](http://ram-pc.de/blogposts/items/dynamic-dns-mit-afraidorg.html) (putting myusername instead of MY-DIRECT-URL-KEY) hasn't given any succes. However, the status field has changed slightly:

```
Dynamic DNS: activated, mydomain.crabdance.com, Status: unknown
```

**Update 2:** So the problem is that accessing the direct update link would work - however my home connection is native IPv6 so it hits freedns.afraid.org via DS-lite, which then doesn't work as a DNS entry. I've contacted the Fritz!Box support team and they said they might implement Dynamic DNS for afraid.org in the next firmware release. Until then I'll look at using MyFritz or an alternative DNS provider.

Comment: Looks like your Afraid.org account is deactivated.  Can you log into the website?

Comment: Yes I can login. I can also edit my DNS records and if I open the update URL in my browser it changes my IP address (but to an IPv4 address - I assume this is because freedns.afraid.org resolves to an IPv4 address which then goes through the tunnel).

Comment: Missed your update. I'm pretty sure what you need (as mentioned in my answer) in place of "MY-DIRECT-URL-KEY" is the "authentication token" per my answer, no username, no password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the support team at AVM was incorrect, the URL for updates supports placeholders for things like IP address. The one for IPv6 address is not listed on the [help page](http://help.avm.de/fritzbox.php?oem=avme&hardware=256&language=en&set=007&topic=hilfe_dyndns&deviceFeatures=1001001111110101011011110100111100011001111100&userSettings=0100) but is `<ip6addr>`. Together with freedns's `address` field this lets me solve the problem.

The following ended up working for me:

```
http://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?MY-SECRET-TOKEN&address=<ip6addr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I'm using a pfSense box, not a Fritz!Box (which I know less than nothing about), but specifically for afraid.org (on the pfSense) the dynamic DNS entry is **not** username/password, it's (blank username, in the password field only) the "authentication token" from freedns.afraid.org, which you can get while logged in, but is *not* your login credentials (uname/pw). So I suspect that part may work the same on "other boxes" even if I don't know much about them.

Works so well it took me a while to find all the info to login again, as I haven't had to since I set it up. If you log into afraid.org, go to Dynamic DNS, select the domain, and look at "quick cron example" the token is the long messy bit after `http://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?`

This is the same thing that gets changed if you ask to "rotate authentication token" on the Dynamic DNS page (and then you need to put the new one into whatever is auto-updating.)

Or, if the Fritz!Box has a rigid dynamic DNS interface but has a crontab, you could use the cron example, I guess - I really know nothing about them. But I do know how I use freedns.afraid.org

Thread at [Nas4Free forums claims Fritzbox does not work with afraid](http://forums.nas4free.org/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=1893) - no real detail, since that's taken as fact and the poster is asking how to have the Nas4Free do the update instead.

This [German Wiki site](http://wiki.ip-phone-forum.de/internet:dns:dyndns) may be of some help (sorry, my German is weak to barely there, but it appears to have instructions for using afraid.org on a fritz!box...or possibly just generic dynamic DNS instructions)

Update: can you cut the user-defined dynamic entry down to JUST

> `Update-URL: https://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/update.php?{insert your authentication token here}`

I think that, alone will update you. While my box uses its password field to store the authentication token, yours may not need to. I know that putting your user name in there is not how freedns.afraid.org works.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth adding, that older Fritzboxes may only work when **omitting** (!) the `http://` from the update-url.

I saw this behaviour with a "FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7570 vDSL".

It would just say something like "Status: Account temporarily deactivated" on the status page, and the system-log would show an error about not being able to resolve the domain name. (Exact german error message: "Dynamic DNS-Fehler: Der angegebene Domainname kann nicht aufgelöst werden.")